# Space bevor the fist Bar in df.plot.bar()

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

The first Bar in the Graph is to much on the left side.
[image: Graph]

I played arraound wirth the two "position" and the "with".

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,2.5), dpi=330)
width=0.4

GV[['A']].plot.bar(position=1, width=width, color=['navy'],ax=ax)
GV[['B']].plot.bar(position=0, width=width, color=['maroon'],ax=ax,yerr=GV[['E']].values.T, error_kw=dict(lw=0.5, capsize=1.5, capthick=0.5))
```

Yes, only the red ones has an y-error.

Comment: do `ax.set_xlim(-1)`?

Comment: Yea, that works :-)